# C++: how to reuse code in covariant return types?

Tags: c++, inheritance, covariance, code-reuse

I have the following simple class

```
class base
{
public:
  int x;
  base &set(int y)
    {
      x = y;
      return *this;
    }
};
```

and want to create a new one with added functionality, say to print the value x. So I do:

```
class derived : public base
{
public:
  void print()
    {
      cout << x << endl;
    }
};
```

Now in the main program I want to do something like

```
D.set(2).print();
```

for which however the compiler complains that class base has no member named 'print'.

If I try to use covariant return types and write the two classes as

```
class base
{
public:
  int x;
  virtual base &set(int y)
    {
      x = y;
      return *this;
    }
};

class derived : public base
{
public:
  derived &set(int y)
    {
      x = y;
      return *this;
    }
  void print()
    {
      cout << x << endl;
    }
};
```

then the statement works just fine, but I was forced to rewrite the exact same function body for 'set' in both classes, even though the only thing that changes is the return type.

If later on I need to change the functionality of base::set then I will have to go through all the derived classes to change the 'set' function... are there any ways to avoid that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you actually create `base` objects or is it intended to be an "abstract" class?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to put `print` on the base and override as needed?

Comment: Why don't you use the first two class examples and make print a virtual method in the base class?

Comment: Please share the code regarding the definition or allocation (**new**) of variables for this class. What do you mean "D" to be?

Comment: @delnan - yes, I plan to create objects of base class.

Comment: @SB - The example I posted here is an (over-)simplification of what I actually need to do. The idea is that 'print' is a functionality only the derived class should have and not the base class. However, both should have the 'set' function doing exactly the same thing but returning different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ work as you say, and you say in your base class `set` return `base&`, so that is what C++ do. But in order to solve this you have many ways.

First you are not forced to make a function `virtual` to override it in a derived class (note that virtual call are slightly slower than normal calls).

Second you can refer to base class implementation as `base::set` so the code will be as follow:

```
class base {
    ...
    base& set( int x ) {...}
};
class derived : public base {
    derived& set( int x ) {
        return static_cast<derived&>( base::set(x) );
    }
};
```

Comment: Yeap, this works just fine, thanks. It is just that I want to avoid casts, I read in another forum that a lot of these means a re-design is in order...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your circumstances, you might be able to use the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
template <class D>
class base {
    D& set(int x) {
        …;
        return *static_cast<D*>(this);
    }
};

class derived : base<derived> { … };
```